# Query in ActiveRecord for objects that contain one or more ids from multiple arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have Rails 5.2 project with three models:

```
class Post
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :post_tags
end

class PostTags
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tags
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :posts, through: :post_tags
end
```

I have the a number of arrays of tag ids, e.g:

```
array_1 = [3, 4, 5]
array_2 = [5, 6, 8]
array_3 = [9, 11, 13]
```

I want a query that will return posts that are tagged with at least one tag with an id from each of the arrays.

For instance, imagine I have a post with the following tag ids:

```
> post = Post.find(1)
> post.tag_ids
> [4, 8]
```

If I ran the query with `array_1` and `array_2` it would return this post. However if I ran it with `array_1`, `array_2` and `array_3` it would not return this post.

I attempted this with the following query:

```
Post.joins(:tags).where('tags.id IN (?) AND tags.id IN (?)', array_1, array_2)
```

But this does not return the post.

What should the query be to return the post?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've tagged this question with postgresql you can perform the query you want using the `intersect` keyword. Unfortunately, activerecord doesn't natively support `intersect` so you'll have to build sql to use this method.

```rb
array_1 = [3, 4, 5]
array_2 = [5, 6, 8]

query = [array_1, array_2].map do |tag_ids|
  Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: tag_ids }).to_sql
end.join(' intersect ')

Post.find_by_sql(query)
```

**Edit**:

We can use subqueries to return the posts and maintain the activerecord relation.

```
array_1 = [3, 4, 5]
array_2 = [5, 6, 8]

Post
  .where(post_tags: PostTag.where(tag_id: array_1))
  .where(post_tags: PostTag.where(tag_id: array_2))
```

For bonus points, you can turn `where(post_tag: PostTag.where(tag_id: array_1))` into a scope on `Posts` and chain as many of them as you'd like.

Comment: that's very good and super close to what I want, but how do I get this to return a Active Record relation object that I can chain rather than a simple array of results?

Comment: I don't think you can get this method to return an AR relation. This method directly executes the sql so it bypasses the relation step. If you're okay with performing two queries you could use the `merge` method to combine this with an active record relation. `some_active_record_relation_on_posts.merge(Post.find_by_sql(query))`

Comment: @NikhilVengal +1 you were definitely on the right track but you can get this query to return in AR. See my post for how to use your intersection but return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: @engineersmnky good call. Using `PostTag` as the intermediary is definitely the right way to go. One note, you can do it more idiomatically without reaching out to arel sql or `intersect`- see the edit on this post.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @NikhilVengal. You should be able to use intersection of 3 scoped queries like so

```
scopes = [array_1,array_2,array_3].map do |arr| 
    Post.joins(:post_tags).where(PostTag.arel_table[:tag_id].in(arr)).arel
end

subquery = scopes.reduce do |memo,scope| 
    # Arel::Nodes::Intersect.new(memo,scope)
    memo.intersect(scope)
end 

Post.from(Arel::Nodes::As.new(subquery,Post.arel_table))
```

This should return `Post` objects that are the intersection of the 3 queries.

Alternatively we can create 3 joins

```
joins = [array_1,array_2,array_3].map.with_index do |arr,idx| 
  alias = PostTag.arel_table.alias("#{PostTag.arel_table.name}_#{idx}")
  Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin.new(
    alias,
    Arel::Nodes::On.new(
      Post.arel_table[:id].eq(alias.arel_table[:post_id])
        .and(alias.arel_table[:tag_id].in(arr))
     )
   )
end

Post.joins(joins).distinct
```

This will create 3 Inner joins with the Post table each being with the PostTag table filtered to the specific tag_ids ensuring that the Post will only show up if it exists in all 3 lists.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `AND` in your where condition is checking for values that intersect (both arrays contain the same values).

```
array_1 = [3, 4, 5]
array_2 = [5, 6, 8]
```

And will return results with `id: 5` since it's in both arrays.

Using an `OR` will get you what you need. Either one of these should work for you:

```
Post.joins(:tags).where('tags.id IN (?) OR tags.id IN (?)', array_1, array_2)
```

OR

```
Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: array_1 + array_2 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @csebryam. Unfortunately that returns any post that has a **any** tag from either array associated with it. I want it to only return posts that have **at least one** tag from **every** array present.

Answer (score 0):

my idea is that you could group by `posts.id` and sum all its tags position in the input array position, suppose you query with 3 group_tags then you have the result like this:

```
post_id  group_tags_1  group_tags_2  group_tags_3 ....
1        2             0             0
2        1             1             1
```

so the final result is the Post with id 2 since it has at least one tag from each group.

```rb
def self.by_group_tags(group_tags)
  having_enough_tags = \
   group_tags.map do |tags|
     sanitize_sql_array(["SUM(array_position(ARRAY[?], tags.id::integer)) > 0", tags])
   end
  
   Post  
    .joins(:tags)
    .group("posts.id")
    .having(
      having_enough_tags.join(" AND ")
    )
end

# Post.by_group_tags([[1,2], [3,4]])
# Post.by_group_tags([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6,7]])
```

**update**:
if you want to go to further chain and should not be effected by `group`, then just simple return a Relation that wrap all post ids you query from `by_group_tags`, such as a `where` as below

```rb
class Post
  def self.by_group_tags(group_tags)
    # ...
  end

  def self.scope_by_group_tags(group_tags)
    post_ids = Post.by_group_tags(group_tags).pluck(:id)
    Post.where(id: post_ids)
  end
end

# Post.scope_by_group_tags([[1,2], [3,4]]).first(10)
```

the drawback: call query the same Posts twice.

Comment: this is a really clever solution. Let me try it and then come back to you.

Comment: unfortunately the `group` function causes problems when I go to further chain this relation with other Active Record relations

Comment: @BetjaminRichards if you want to go to further chain, then just simple return a Relation that wrap all ids you query from `by_group_tags` such as a `where`, take a look my updated.